Infinite descending chain in R
I'm new to ZFC set theory.
As i understand, the axiom of regularity is to prevent the existence of an infinite descending chain.
In $\mathbb{R}$, I see clearly that for example the sequence 0, -1, ..., $-\infty$ (but i don't mean $\infty$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$, just to indicate that it is decreasing) is clearly an infinite descending chain with respect to the usual $<$ ordering in $\mathbb{R}$.
Could you please help me figure out this confusion ? Thank you very much!

The axiom of regularity is about the relation $\in$ on sets, not the relation $<$ on real numbers. $x<y$ does not imply $x\in y$.

The axiom of regularity implies

there is no infinite sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_{i+1}$ is an
element of $a_i$ for all $i$.

(from Wikipedia)
That rules out a particular kind of infinite descending chain of sets. It says nothing about infinite descending chains in other order relations.

Thanks!!! Can you please explain me why do we don't want to have infinte descending chain w.r.t to $\in$ ?

@InTheSearchForKnowledge You want some kind of restriction that avoids Russell's paradox.

And it is not because we want to be able to do induction ? I think avoiding Rusell's paradox is just a nice side effect... but i'm not sure.

@InTheSearchForKnowledge It disables Russell. You don't need it enable induction.

I don't get what you meant. can you please be a little bit more specific ? Thanks!

@InTheSearchForKnowledge It's hard to be more specific. You don't want a system in which you can write Russell's paradox. The axiom of regularity prevents that. It  has nothing to do with induction in the integers or the descending chain of real numbers in the question.

Ah, i didn't mean the induction in the integers. Sorry about that. What i mean is that Axiom of regularity ensures that all the sets are well-founded, which enables the possibility of doing induction. And the side effect is that there is no Russell's paradox. Hope i'm clear...

@InTheSearchForKnowledge  The regularity axiom says the $\in$ relation is well founded. Independent of that axiom, you can do induction on any relation that is well founded. (This is my last comment on this question. Set theory is not my specialty.)

@InTheSearchForKnowledge Yes, thanks to the axiom you can prove statements about all sets by arguing by induction on its elements ($\in$-induction), that is, to prove that all sets have some property $\phi$, it is enough to show that, for any $x$, if $\forall y\in x,\phi(y)$, then $\phi(x)$.

@EthanBolker Regularity has nothing to do with disabling Russell's paradox. I don't know why this misconception has spread so much.

@JonathanSchilhan Thanks. I learned something.
